# How to set class name for created divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, I've created a list of `div` elements and I want to set a `class name` **only for 1st, 3rd and 4th elements** of this list. Is it possible?

I've tried to use `setAttribute` but got nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var newsListData = [
    {
        "title" : "title",
    },
    {
        "title" : "title",
    },
    {
        "title" : "title",
    },
    {
        "title" : "title",
    }
]



window.onload=function(index){
    var divList;
    for (var i = 0; i < newsListData.length; i++){
        divList = document.createElement("div");
        divList.innerHTML = newsListData[i].title;
        document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].appendChild(divList);
        divList[0].setAttribute("class", "sample"); // stuck here
    }
    
}
```

```css
.sample {
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="list">
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
window.onload=function(index){
    var divList;
    for (var i = 0; i < newsListData.length; i++){
    divList = document.createElement("div");
    divList.innerHTML = newsListData[i].title;
    document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].appendChild(divList);
    divList.setAttribute("class", "sample"); // stuck here

  }
  var second = document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[1];
  second.setAttribute("class", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `divList` as if it is an array when it is not.

```
divList[0].setAttribute("class", "sample"); // stuck here
```

You should just use `divList.setAttribute(...)`. Here it is fixed:

```js
var newsListData = [
    {"title" : "title",},
 {"title" : "title",},
 {"title" : 'title',},
 {"title" : 'title',}
];

window.onload=function(index){
    var divList;
    for (var i = 0; i < newsListData.length; i++){
    divList = document.createElement("div");
    divList.innerHTML = newsListData[i].title;
    document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0].appendChild(divList);
    if(i !== 1 ){ 
      divList.setAttribute("class", "sample"); // fixed
    }
  }
    
}
```

```css
.sample {
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="list">
            
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps suggest the use of `.classList.add()` instead of `setAttribute`

Comment: Huh, it's ok but I want to set this class only to 1st and 2nd elements(for example) not to every element

Comment: @Martin `if(i==0 || i==2 || i==3) { divList.setAttribute("class", "sample"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use className attribute instead `divList.className = 'sample'`